# Отправка в форме данных из редактора Quill

Tags: javascript, php, form, input, редактор

Использую на одном из сайтов текстовый редактор Quill

```
<script src='https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.0/quill.min.js'></script>
<link href='https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.0/quill.snow.css' rel='stylesheet'>



<form action="" method="post">
           <div class="editorTxt">
           </div>
            <input type="submit" name="sendComment">
</form>


<script>
    var quill = new Quill('.editorTxt', {
    modules: {
    formula: true,
    toolbar: [
    ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
    ['image', 'blockquote', 'code-block'],
    [{ 'list': 'ordered'}, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
    [{ 'indent': '-1'}, { 'indent': '+1' }],
    [{ 'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }],
    [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
    [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],
    [{ 'font': [] }],
    [{ 'align': [] }],
    ['formula'],
    ['clean']     
    ]
    },
    placeholder: 'Введите ваш комментарий',
    theme: 'snow'
    });
</script>
```

В месте дива **.editorTxt** появляется собственно сам редактор.

ВОПРОС: как отправить в форме данные введённые в редакторе?

Comment: В документации всё есть, в чём проблема? https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#content

Comment: Всё прекрасно, только я в js не тикаю практически, может быть есть готовый пример у кого?

Comment: Ну так учите JS, всё что вам нужно это получить данные и с помощью метода `getContents` описанного в документации а затем отправьте их с помощью `XMLHttpRequest` документация по `xhr`: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Спасибо умник за совет!

Comment: У тебя какая-то странная установка, что тебе кто-то что-то должен. Когда тебе помогают, скидывая нужные ссылки, ты огрызаешься и ждёшь пока за тебя напишут код

Comment: Просто то, что ты мне написал я и без тебя знаю. Пошёл учить JS по твоей установке...

Comment: Если знаешь, то не составит труда написать нужный код =)